# Why is JSLint telling me "Use the array literal notation []."

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have this code:

```
    // ...
    return Array.apply(null, new Array(length)).map(elementfn);
```

And for that line, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) is telling me

> Use the array literal notation [].

How is it possible to use literal notation when I don't know the length at design time?

Comment: Seems fine. I gave up on JSLint a while ago. I suggest JSHint, is more configurable.

Comment: While JSLint is obviously wrong about this one, I wouldn't call it good, readable code.  If you need a loop, why not to use a loop?

Comment: @Bakudan: This is not a duplicate.  I know the difference.  For example, you can provide a length to the constructor, which I am doing.

Comment: @recursive Ok, I thought the example was pointing the reason why JSlint suggest why use "[]", sorry, my mistake. Additionally I'm not exactly sure why you need the size. This is not Java (or C#), where the array have fixed size. In JavaScript you can add as many elements as you want. I suppose JSLint is just looking for the "new Array(...)", and didn't try to check if it is correctly used or something.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript it is not needed to enter a length when constructing the array. They automatically change their size.

Comment: In the mentioned usecase an empty array is not suitable. With an empty array, the initialization using the `map()` method will fail. One could rewrite the code completely, but that is not the subject of the question.

Comment: They only change their size when elements are added to them.  In this case, I have a variable containing the length I know I want the array to be.

Comment: you can always just set array.length = length

Comment: @recursive: I agree with MrP. The following code get no errors/warning: `function test(length, elementfn) { "use strict"; var ar = []; ar.length = length; return Array.apply(null, ar).map(elementfn); }`

Answer (score 0):

JSLint is optimized to use best practices and speed up your scripts. Array literal notation is seen as being faster as it does not have the overhead of a call to the Array constructor. That is at least my take on it.

Comment: It is not possible to use an array literal to represent an array of unknown length.